# Freetext or HTML for ExtJS TriggerField?

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to insert freetext or HTML to the "trigger" element of a TriggerField, instead of just an icon? For example, can we do something like the following (screenshot of bootstrap's input-addon feature):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trigger icon as defined in Triton theme is a "text" - a unicode character from [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

Using `cls` and some CSS definitions, you can replace it with any text you like.

Below is the code for the FontAwesome mail icon, but you can insert any text into "content".

ExtJS:

```
triggers: {
    sendmail: {
        cls: 'icon-mail',
```

CSS:

```
.icon-mail {
    background:none
}
.icon-mail:before {
    content:'\f0e0';
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    line-height:1
}
```

Using CSS, you can try to restyle the existing icon HTML, but to add more HTML, you have to derive the component and exchange the template, and be really careful to not break anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have thought about that approach as well but decided against it as it's simply too much of a hack for me =)